# How to use Python requests to simultaneously download and upload a file

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to stream a download from an nginx server and simultaneously upload it. The download is using requests stream implementation; the upload is using chunking - the intention is to be able to report progress as the down/upload is occurring.

The overall code of what I've got so far is like so:

```
with closing(requests.get(vmdk_url, stream=True, timeout=60 + 1)) as vmdk_request:
    chunk_in_bytes = 50 * 1024 * 1024
    total_length = int(vmdk_request.headers['Content-Length'])

    def vmdk_streamer():
        sent_length = 0
        for data in vmdk_request.iter_content(chunk_in_bytes):
            sent_length += len(data)
            progress_in_percent = (sent_length / (total_length * 1.0)) * 100

            lease.HttpNfcLeaseProgress(int(progress_in_percent))
            yield data

    result = requests.post(
        upload_url, data=vmdk_streamer(), verify=False,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-vnd.vmware-streamVmdk'})
```

Which, in a certain set of contexts, works fine. I put it into another (a Cloudify plugin, if you're interested) and when it reaches around 60s it fails to read data.

So I'm looking for an alternative - or simply better - way of streaming a download/upload as my 60s issue might revolve around how I'm streaming (I hope). Preferably with `requests` but really I'd use anything up to and including raw `urllib3`.